# How to remove git bash ssh authentication on windows

Tags: windows, git, github, ssh

Whenever i go to do some operation on Windows involving my remote repository like `git pull`, `git remote update` or `git push` (among others) Windows keeps asking me to inform my SSH key. Is there any way to stop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. As described at: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#auto-launching-ssh-agent-on-git-for-windows

> You can run ssh-agent automatically when opening bash or the Git
> shell. Copy the following lines and paste them into the `~/.profile`
> or `~/.bashrc` file in Git Shell:

```
# Auto-launching ssh-agent on Git for Windows
env=~/.ssh/agent.env

agent_load_env () { test -f "$env" && . "$env" >| /dev/null ; }

agent_start () {
    (umask 077; ssh-agent >| "$env")
    . "$env" >| /dev/null ; }

agent_load_env

# agent_run_state: 0=agent running w/ key; 1=agent w/o key; 2=agent not running
agent_run_state=$(ssh-add -l >| /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?)

if [ ! "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] || [ $agent_run_state = 2 ]; then
    agent_start
    ssh-add
elif [ "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] && [ $agent_run_state = 1 ]; then
    ssh-add
fi

unset env
```

But in my case I didn't have those files mentioned so what I did was create in my `C:\Users\<username>` directory a file called `.bashrc` and paste the code indicated.

It could be that the first time you open your git bash or try to do some operation involving the remote it will ask you for your password, but after you enter this first time it will not ask for any more.